# Woocommerce Checkout Quantity AJAX Update

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a quantity box to my woocommerce checkout page, and it works fine. If i type a new number into the box and then click outside the box the checkout is updated. However I am trying to add plus and minus buttons to the quantity field but I can't make it detect the updated value.

For testing purposes I am trying:

```
jQuery("#quantity_62e84eb438cdc").val(15);
$( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_checkout' );
```

The value is updated, but the checkout isn't updated. Is there a alternative trigger to use?

Comment: add your + - elements in your quantity box and detect when user click to add or remove from total and trigger update. I prefer manual update since user may want to increase or decrese more and have to wait every time but its up to you.

Comment: Thats my problem though, how do i trigger the update?

Comment: Here is a example - https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/remove-update-cart-button.html similar solutions you can find here too

Comment: Sadly that still doesn't help, as the JavaScript code is just clicking the update cart button. But that button doesn't exist on checkout

Comment: Then just add it ? who said has to be visible :) I recommend not modify core stuff bcs plugins and themes rely on those and you may face problems in future.